# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "lottie-ios"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

i can't install react-native-lottie throwing error compatatible version for lottie-react-native  CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "lottie-ios"

Answer (score 55, accepted):

as per the error says we need to go for

```
npm i lottie-ios@3.1.8 lottie-react-native@3.5.0
cd ios
pod install
```

Issue resolved!
Obviously install npm onto this MacOS box first.

Comment: Using these specific versions solved it for me as well. I guess using latest versions was the issue

Comment: The above answer works fine. Just make sure to delete node_modules, podfile.lock, and pods folder before reinstalling the dependencies. Which ensures it works.

Comment: From Lottie's official docs they've updated the version to lottie-ios@3.2.3

https://github.com/lottie-react-native/lottie-react-native#installing-react-native--0600

Comment: if I downgrade the lottie-react-native@5.1.4 to lottie-react-native@3.5.0 IOS is working fine but I am getting errors in the android build

Answer (score 11):

If you get something like this,

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "lottie-ios":
  In Podfile:
    lottie-ios (from `../node_modules/lottie-ios`)

    lottie-react-native (from `../node_modules/lottie-react-native`) was resolved to 3.5.0, which depends on
      lottie-ios (~> 3.1.8)
```

Then we can resolve it by the following steps,

- Open terminal in root folder of your react native project.
- Execute the following commands to install `lottie-ios` and `lottie-react-native` packages with the specified version of the cocoa pod error.

  ```
  npm install lottie-ios@3.1.8 
  npm install lottie-react-native@3.5.0
  ```
- After these package addition move to ios folder and run pod install.

  ```
  cd ios
  pod install
  ```

Answer (score 4):

Solved this issue by uninstalling the previous installed Lottie version and then

```
1- yarn add lottie-react-native@4.0.3
2- yarn add lottie-ios@3.2.3
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to upgrade your `platform :ios` version in your PODFILE

In my case,I changed  `platform :ios` from 10 to 11, and everything worked well

Comment: The line should look like `platform :ios, '12.1'`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version of react-native version that we use. For me, it's **npm i --save lottie-react-native
npm i --save lottie-ios@3.2.3**
since, my react-native version is 0.68.2.
You can check the compatible version for your react-native version from the link below:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/lottie-react-native

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

We need to go for:

```
npm i lottie-ios@3.1.8 lottie-react-native@3.5.0 cd ios pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the latest version of lottie-react-native with react-native version of >=0.66, add lottie-ios@3.2.3

`>= 0.66    latest  3.2.3`

Related link: https://github.com/lottie-react-native/lottie-react-native#versioning

Answer (score 0):

Do not update the `lottie` version, instead of that try this:

**Step 1**

add `pod 'lottie-ios'` in Pod file.

**Step 2**

do `pod install`

This is worked for me